# How to access instance attributes in decorator argument?

Tags: typescript, decorator

I'm trying to eliminate code duplication by defining an abstract class to process queues. I'm using decorators provided by [ssut/nestjs-sqs](https://github.com/ssut/nestjs-sqs/), but here's a more simple example to illustrate my problem:

```js
function enumerable(value: boolean) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    descriptor.enumerable = value;
  };
}

abstract class MyClass {
  abstract isEnumerable: boolean

  @enumerable(this.isEnumerable)
  myMethod() {

  }
}
```

The scope of `this` in the decorator argument is not the class instance, as the error message from TS transpiler says:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.

How can I use instance properties on a method decorator?

Comment: You can't. Method decorators are called only **once**, at the start of the program, not for every instance.

Comment: Thanks, @caTS. Do you have any suggestion to use a library like [ssut/nestjs-sqs](https://github.com/ssut/nestjs-sqs/) in multiple queues with similar processing methods without too much code duplication?